Publishing parts of my thesis under Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 License in journals
I am about to electronically "publish" my PhD thesis under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 License. Some chapters will eventually be published in journals, and I am wondering if that type of license can cause problems. In particular, I am considering a Springer journal. I couldn't find any information on that. I suppose we have to be careful in the type of license we use for the thesis, depending on what journals require on their end. Should I use another license instead?

Depending on the journal, you may also want to check the policy on prior publication.

Before you "publish" yourself, understand the specific policies of any journals you might want to submit to. In particular, Some (at least) Springer journals permit publishing on "preprint servers", but it may not extend beyond that.
For preprint policies see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_publishers_by_preprint_policy
The license question is a bit different, since a license affects copyright and what you can give a formal publisher. CC Attribution is quite generous, which means a lot of rights are already given up. Again, know the policies of the publishers you are considering
For copyright policy guidance see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_policies_of_academic_publishers
